# Json Output of a C# WebMethod Does Not Affect a JQuery's DataTable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables, webmethod

I've been stuck with this issue for a while now, each time getting a different error or some sort of a problem which does not help me achieve my goal.

I am using the table plug-in for jQuery and I can't seem to get a proper Json response from me ASP.NET WebMethod which would fit as the table's data. The state of my table is stuck on "Loading.." and nothing seems to happen, even though I do receive a proper Json response from my WebMethod. It just doesn't seem to affect my dataTable, or just freezes it up during the initialization due to some issue.

My code:

Client-Side:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="DataTables-1.10.4/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/Scroller/css/dataTables.scroller.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>first name</th>
                <th>last name</th>
                <th>position</th>
                <th>office</th>
                <th>start_date</th>
                <th>salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>first name</th>
                <th>last name</th>
                <th>position</th>
                <th>office</th>
                <th>start_date</th>
                <th>salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="DataTables-1.10.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="DataTables-1.10.4\extensions\Scroller\js\dataTables.scroller.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#example').dataTable({
            //"ajax": "ajaxtest.txt",
            "ajax": {
                "url": "WebService.asmx/GetTable",
                "type": "POST"
            },
            "deferRender": true
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My WebService.asmx:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public WebService () {
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void GetTable() {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string response = js.Serialize(Person.GetPersons());

        Context.Response.Clear();
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", response.Length.ToString());
        Context.Response.Flush();

        Context.Response.Write(response);
    }
}
```

My Json response (valid):

```
[{"first_name":"Thomas","last_name":"Vincunas","position":"Manager","office":"066843-4120","start_date":"12/12/1995","salary":"$124,081"},{"first_name":"David","last_name":"Naidich","position":"Worker","office":"052-343-4120","start_date":"12/11/1990","salary":"$124,081"},{"first_name":"Barak","last_name":"Obama","position":"Co-Manager","office":"1505465460","start_date":"13/04/1985","salary":"$124,081"},{"first_name":"Vincent","last_name":"Gambino","position":"Unemployed","office":"5313","start_date":"12/01/1980","salary":"$124,081"}]
```

As stated above, nothing happens once the page has successfully loaded. The table just shows the headers and a "Loading..." text, and that's about it. I'm a bit lost now, tried pretty much anything by now.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check your browser's JavaScript console. Do you see an error message?

Comment: @mason No errors nor warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON doesn't match the format that [the documentation](http://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html) specifies it needs.

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "System Architect",
      "Edinburgh",
      "5421",
      "2011/04/25",
      "$320,800"
    ],
    [
      "Garrett Winters",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "8422",
      "2011/07/25",
      "$170,750"
    ],
    [
      "Ashton Cox",
      "Junior Technical Author",
      "San Francisco",
      "1562",
      "2009/01/12",
      "$86,000"
    ]
]
}
```

The example shows JSON with a root object of `data`, with each row being its own array. Or there is an [alternate format](http://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html) with objects, but it still requires a `root` object. Modify the JSON you're returning to match one of the expected formats.

By the way, you're using `WebMethod` which is [no longer supported](https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/more-reasons-to-not-use-asmx-services-in-new-code/). You should switch to [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).